# NP-completeness certificate of a Hamiltonian path

Tags: np-complete, hamiltonian-path

A Hamiltonian path is a path in a directed , edge positive valued finite graph which visits every vertex exactly once and returns to the original vertex.
This should be a NP-complete problem, but I do not see the membership into the class NP: what is the polynomial time verifiable certificate of this problem membership to NP?

Comment: A Hamilton path is a certificate that can be checked in linear time.

Comment: But when the edges are valued by non-negative reals, is it still the case that such a **shortest** path has a P-time certificate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the "edge-positive".  That is not part of the usual definition of [Hamilton path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) which has nothing to do with edge weights.

Comment: So you think that this case is provably beyond NP?Even for weights 1 and 2 only? Thank you.

Comment: No, I didn't say that.  I have no opinion on the matter.

Comment: What do the edge values have to do with the problem?  You never specified this.

Comment: I've slightly modified the definition. Instead of an existence of a Hamiltonian path, I now assume that besides its existence, each edge has its weight: a non-negative real number (to avoid negative cycles). This is not standard. However we can certainly assume this modification. Now I thought that the shortest path should be in NP, and hence it should have a P-time certificate. However, I'm not convinced it is the case. The question is into which natural complexity class this "SHORTEST HAMILTONIAN PATH PROBLEM" naturally fits into.